# How to use `$axios` in utility function in Vuex of Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I am configuring VUEX of Nuxt.js as follows.

```
store
├── README.md
├── posts
│   ├── actions.js
│   ├── getters.js
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── mutations.js
│   └── utils
│       └── getPostById.js
└── index.js
```

I added `@nuxtjs/axios` to modules in nuxt.config.js and make it possible to use `this.$axios.$get` in actions.
However, you can not use A in store/posts/utils/getPostById.js.
An error of `Cannot read property '$axios' of undefined` will occur.

Each code is described as follows.

・ store/index.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import postsModule from './posts'

new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    posts: postsModule
  }
})
```

・store/posts/index.js

```
import actions from './actions'
import getters from './getters'
import mutations from './mutations'

export const state = () => ({
  posts: [],
  post: {}
})

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations
}
```

・ store/posts/actions.js

```
import getPostById from './utils/getPostById'

export default {
  async fetchPost({ commit }, count = 10) {
    const params = { count: count }
    // Here `$axios` can be used normally
    const result = await this.$axios.$get("ApiUrl")
    commit('setPosts', result)
  },
  async fetchPostById({ commit }, category_ids, count = 10) {
    const topCommunities = {}
    const result = await getPostById(id)
    commit('setPost', result)
  }
}
```

・ store/posts/utils/getPostById.js

```
export default async function(post_id) {
  // Here `$axios` can not use
  const result = await this.$axios.$get(`${ApiUrl}/${post_id}`)
  return result
}
```

How can I use `this.$axios.$get` inside `getPostById.js`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can only access axios in your nuxtServerInit() under actions in your store like so

```
async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { $axios }) {
  const ip = await $axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com')
  commit('SET_IP', ip)
}
```

Check this page https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage for more information on how to use axios in NuxtJS projects.

Answer (score 14):

Quite a few things have changed since the question was posted. You can now access the `$axios` utility in the store via `this.$axios`. The nuxt plugin uses `inject` to make the `$axios` object available in the store as described [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#combined-inject).

As an example:

```
export const actions = {
    async fetchUser () {
        let user = await this.$axios.$get('/me');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is straight use of `axios` module in `nuxt.js`

1. **Components**

**asyncData**

```js
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
  const ip = await $axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com')
  ....
}
```

**methods/created/mounted/etc**

```js
methods: {
  async fetchSomething() {
    const ip = await this.$axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com')
    ....
  }
}
```

2. **Store Actions**

```js
{
  actions: {
    async getIP ({ commit }) {
      const ip = await this.$axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com')
      .......
    }
  }
}
```

3. **Shortcuts**

```js
// Normal usage with axios
let data = (await $axios.get('...')).data

// Fetch Style
let data = await $axios.$get('...')
```

here up are the ways you can use to access `nuxt.js` `$axios` module

keep in mind that this was the new `v5.12.3` release when this answer was made

also check this [axios module link from nuxt js website](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage)